# If I restore from an iCloud Backup will my photos go back into Camera roll

Tags: itunes, icloud, ipod-touch

I an trying to sync my iPod Touch 5 to iTunes but had reset my PC. Now I need to erase everything off my iPod Touch.

If I restore from an iCloud Backup will my photos go back into Camera roll?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will restore your photos from your camera roll

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12519?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US